# How to convert a collection of JSON objects into YAML in php

Tags: php, json, yaml

I'm calling an API that is returning a collection of objects back to me in JSON, as I go through this collection of objects, I need to some of the properties of each object to create a YAML map, that I can use in a different project.

The JSON object looks like this:

```
    stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => uuid-unique-identifier
        [name] => name
        [cname] => something.example.com 
        [environment] => production
        [primary_domain] => primarydomain1.com
    )
```

The YAML file needs to look like this

```
    sites: 
     - name: name1
       url: primarydomain1.com
     - name: name2
       url: primarydomain2.com
```

What I'm struggling with is, making an array/data structure that can be used by the Symfony Yaml component (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html) to dump out Yaml in the format that I want it.

The PHP code that is iterating through the collection of objects is building an array like this

```
    foreach ($objects AS $object) {
     $installsToMonitor[] = array('name' => $object->name, 
                                  'url' => $object->primary_domain);
    }
    $yaml = Yaml::dump($installsToMonitor);
    echo $yaml;
```

Which is outputting invalid YAML like this..

```
    -
        name: name1
        url: primarydomain1.com
    -
        name: name2
        url: primarydomain2.com
```

My ultimate goal is to build a YAML string that I can insert into the .upptimerc.yml file, so that I can monitor all my sites easily. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something silly with how I'm building the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing one level on the `array` you use to generate the **YAML** code, that allows you to represent the `sites` object.

So your loop needs to be writing the various `$object` properties within an `$installsToMonitor['sites']` array.

In Code:

```
$installsToMonitor = ['sites' => []];
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    $installsToMonitor['sites'][] = [
        'name' => $object->name,
        'primary_domain' => $object->primary_domain
    ];
}
```

This will correctly output

```
---
sites:
- name: name
  primary_domain: primarydomain1.com
- name: name2
  primary_domain: primarydomain2.com
```

Also, if you want to make your code independent from a framework, you can use **YAML** `pecl` extension and use `yaml_emit` - [Official Docs here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-emit.php)

Comment: I tried that, but then I got this output https://gist.github.com/vidluther/d19ce018972c0a8600a9daf4b6e8cb9d

Comment: I don't understand, isn't the output in my answer the one you were looking for? That's the output you get from the code above

Comment: I tried it, here's the actual code in Github, I tried copy/pasting your code and I'm still getting the weird YAML, I guess my next step is to figure out how to build a Docker image that has the pecl extension built in and then try the yaml_emit.  https://github.com/vidluther/wphinspector/blob/main/src/upptime.php

Comment: This works, with the yaml pecl extension installed.

Comment: Great to hear that! Not sure why the Symphony YAML module doesn't output this correctly